# Cannot change permission or delete /root/.composer directory

Tags: docker, composer-php

Here is the scenario. I have a PHP Docker with the Composer installed, then I tried to use composer package from other repositories and do a composer update. I got the following error:

> Cannot create cache directory /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

I know something wrong with /root/.composer directory.
I tried to change the permission and delete it, but I couldn't:

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqnpm.png)

Basically, I cannot do anything with "/root/.composer".
How can I change permission or delete this folder?

Comment: You are running Composer as root in the container?

Comment: There is only one user in PHP Docker image. So, it doesn't matter you use root or non-root user. Anyway, thanks for asking. I've already found the root cause of this problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. The problem is the way to install Composer.

**This sequence will cause an ERROR above:**

1. Dockerfile

`RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
RUN php composer-setup.php --filename=composer
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

2. Run docker-compose

`docker-compose up -d`

**Solution:**

1. Dockerfile

DO NOT install Composer from Dockerfile

2. Run docker-compose

`docker-compose up -d`

3. Inside the container - install composer

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php --filename=composer
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`